# How to make a component rerender even if the state does not change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to rerender a component in React Native even if the state has not changed. I realise that if it is assigned the same value on `setState()` of a variable, the update of the component is not done.

How to force it to update?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with an explanation as to why you need this. There may be lateral solutions based on what you need.

Comment: All react components have a method that does exactly this, literally `this.forceUpdate()`. That being said, @Soviut raises a good point, you probably don't actually want to use this

Comment: why you want to render?? if state has not changed.

Comment: The parent of that component can set a `key` on it, or you could use the [`forceUpdate()` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate).